# jquery sprite animation responsive

Tags: jquery, animation, sprite, scale

I want to replace a two image gif animation with a sprite.
The problem is, that I am using a responsive design. So when the window size changes, the whole "system" is not working any longer. The gif is bad, and cpu eating, but it scales right.

So my question - as I found no solution - is it possible to get the window size from the actual window, scaling the image to the right height, width and of course changes the "jump" from 1st image to 2nd image and so on.

```
var scrollUp = (function () {

  var timerId;

  return function (height, times, element) {
    var i = 0;
    timerId = setInterval(function () {
      if (i > times)
        i = 0;
      element.style.backgroundPosition = "0px -" + i * height + 'px';
      i ++;
    }, 100  );
  };
})( );

scrollUp( 1200 ,   6, document.getElementById('anim'))
```

So at this code the image size is set to 1200 - thats right, if the display is 1980x1200, but as the display changes, the size 1200 is wrong - it should be the actual display size - at the same time, the image should be scaled to that size.

Is something like this possible? Or has anybody a better idea for an eays responsive sprite animation?

maybe css3?

thanks!

AD

Comment: Why not use CSS media queries to respond to screen size changes at breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function myAss(){ //when window is resizing it starts
    var wid = $(window).width();
    //or
    var wid = $("#someid").width();
    //or
    var wid = $(".someclass").width();
    $("#yourdiv").css("width",wid*0.5); //your div will be 50% of the received width. do same with the height if you want.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with CSS only. If your sprite has (for example) 5 images, then set the background-size to 500%. It worked for me. [Working example](http://www.arnojansen.eu/davidu/huis-3.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [LazyLou](https://github.com/ozanmuyes/lazylou) and stay tuned for v1.1. I'm the developer of this plugin and I'm planning to add add-on architecture on v1.1. The first add-on for the plugin will be animator.